# Assign candidates to groups based on scores obtained using asp.net, C# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Please experts, I want to automatically assign candidates to different groups based on their scores obtained starting from the highest score. There are 100 candidates I want the first  20 candidates with the highest score assigned to “Group A”, the next 20 to ” Group B”, the next 20 to ” Group C”  and so on. Am using asp.net MVC and C#.

> Database Name: **candidatesDB**
>
> Fields in candidates table
>     candidateID
>     Firstname
>     Lastname
>     Candidatescores

and

> Grouping Table: (data here assigned from the candidate table)
>   Firstname
>   Lastname group

In my Controller

```
public ActionResult autoassign()
{
    var rc = new CandidateDBEntities();

    var res = (from p in rc.candidates
        orderby p.candidatescores descending
            select new {
                firstname = p.firstname.ToString(),
                lastname = p.lastname.ToString(),
                score = f.canditatescores.ToString()
            });

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        foreach (var item in res)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=candidatesDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Grouping values ('" + item.firstname + "','" + item.lastname + "','GroupA')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    for (var i = 20; i <= 40; i++)
    {
        foreach (var item in res)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=candidatesDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Grouping values ('" + item.firstname + "','" + item.lastname + "','GroupB')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

And so on

When I run the codes I do not get the required results. I don’t know what to do or how to go about it. Professionals here could help me.

Comment: Why write the results of this grouping?  Why not just have a query when you need it?  As an aside, I'm not sure why you're creating new `SqlConnection` objects when you're using Entity Framework.  If you really need raw SQL use `rc.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`.

Comment: Also, am I crazy or is the looping logic not doing what is intended at all? Try a single [ for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) ] and [ res[i].whateverCol ] for the values --get rid of the nested foreach loops. This ought to at least satisfy that portion of the problem.